# Laptop is clean but has high temperature

Tags: laptop, temperature, gaming

My laptop (Acer Predator 17 G9-792) has a high temperature while gaming.

**Specifications:**

- 16GB Ram
- Intel core i7-6700HQ 2.60GHz
- Windows 10 pro
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 980M

I cleaned the dust a couple of times today with a hair dryer.
All the options and battery options are set to performance.

Details:
Temperature:

- **CPU:**

  - 30-40 (idle)
  - 85-97 (gaming)
- **System:**

  - 30-40 (idle)
  - 80 (gaming)

**Fan speed:**
**CPU:** 3800 - 4200 RPM
**System:** 3900 - 4100 RPM
**FrostCore:** 3700 RPM

I tried to update my drivers but they are already up to date.
I have also enabled the option for `Max fan speed`
So what could possibly be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you ever monitored the temps when it was new? Some laptops do run on the hot side, especially gaming ones. Based on some forums I've looked at, a lot of people have this same laptop that run as hot as yours.

Comment: I have actually, but I don't remember the results. Besides, I think the 90+ temps are a recent activity.. And should I not be considered about it? Because if a lot of people have the same laptop with the same temps then maybe it's not such a big deal? but still kinda scary

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning dust out with a hair-drier is going to do little-to-no good.

It is likely that your heatsinks are blocked with fluff/dust (Assuming this is an older laptop, and this has only recently become a problem), you need to blast the dust out with an air-line or an air-duster, as the fluff/dust tends to "cake" into the fins of the heatsinks.

Blow INTO the hot air exhausts with high pressure air and behold as plumes of skin and fluff fill the air.